# Align TextView correctly with a Spinner in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-constraintlayout

I have a activity layout which represents a form. The form contains a few form fields including an Spinner.

The layout is of type ConstraintLayout.

[image]

Because the Spinner control doesn't have a baseline i can't vertical align my "Kind" label correctly. I used 24 dp at the top as a temp. solution, but because the Spinner will increase in height i don't like this solution.

Is there a better solution to get the Kind label aligned correctly?

Comment: why constraintlayout? you can use relative or linearlayout also.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 ConstraintLayout is much better than the others in terms of performance. Plus, it allows you to have a flat hierarchy no matter the complexity of the layout.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 back in the days i used to work with relative and linearlayout but i'm glad i don't have to go back. Constraintlayout is easy and very powerful to use.

Comment: @OkwanTegls i am not saying not to use constraint layout...whatever fits ur reqirement...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/video"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spinner" />
```

When you anchor the bottom and top of a view to another, it will be centered relatively. This is valid vertically and horizontally.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the TextView and the Spinner aligned better when using baseline alignment (`layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`).

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Repeat"/>

<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/textview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
```